# IE Standard vs Quirks Handling of offsetLeft

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer

We are modifying an older pre-existing web app and as part of that have begun viewing it using IE10.  This app has a third party menu control (menu9_com.js?) and among the numerous issues we are noticing, is the positioning of this menu on IE7+ in Standards mode.  In FF, Chrome, or any version of IE with Quirks - it is positioned correctly.  In Standards mode, however, it is shoved far off to the right.

I've identified the function below as a possible source for the issue.  Running in any mode, the value of StartLeft begins about the same.  In the working modes it finishes at a value which - by definition - works.  In the broken modes, it is much much higher.

Though it's not fully clear, I believe the function is walking up the DOM from a given target location and adding values on to calculate a "total" offset for the menu element it is adding.  And I think the issue comes down to the different ways that offsetLeft (and maybe offsetParent?) are handled.  So I'm trying to find the best way to get consistent behavior from this function but just not familiar enough with the intention of the function, nor with the behavior of offsetLeft etc in the various modes.

Here's the function:

```
function ClcTrgt() {
    var TLoc=Nav4?FLoc.document.layers[TargetLoc]:DomYesFLoc.document.getElementById(TargetLoc):FLoc.document.all[TargetLoc];
    if (DomYes) {
        while (TLoc) {
            StartTop += TLoc.offsetTop;
            StartLeft += TLoc.offsetLeft;
            TLoc = TLoc.offsetParent;
        }
    }
    else {
        StartTop+=Nav4?TLoc.pageY:TLoc.offsetTop;
        StartLeft+=Nav4?TLoc.pageX:TLoc.offsetLeft;
    }
}
```

Any suggestions?  For example, I'd convert this function to use jQuery, if I knew how.

UPDATE:
I've posted the script on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/hAb1KU9g).

Comment: Nothing like seeing a check for Netscape Navigator 4 from 1997.

Comment: I think `document.getElementById(TargetLoc)` targets the element in all used browsers. However, your codesnippet shows only how you calculate the position. You should also show your relevant HTML and CSS, and how you actually use the calculated values. A [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) would be very helpful.

Comment: There's nothing in [CSSOM](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/cssom/) to suggest that the offset* properties are processed differently in quirks mode (unlike the scroll* and client* properties), so I wonder whether the different value for StartLeft is symptom, rather than cause.

Comment: @Alohci Omitting units would make a difference. Though this probably is not the issue, since OP says the positioning is correct for other modern browsers...

Comment: @Teemu - That's not how I read the question. The OP says its positioning is right in modern browsers in quirks mode, but not standards mode. I think you are most likely right. Unitless lengths is what I would be looking for first.

Comment: @Alohci I've read the question several times, still understand the code is working in all browsers (also in Standards mode) except in IE7+, in these it's working only in Quirks mode. I might be wrong with this : ). Anyway, the snippet OP has posted, is not enough to solve the problem, we need to wait more code to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

My current direction, in the absence of an actual fix to the script (which may not be worth the work), is adding this function to run after the script itself.  I added some markup to facilitate it, and it just takes the menu, and puts it where it should be (which it right-aligned with another element I've identified).  This is for from optimal, but it works.

```
function fixMenu9() {
    var pTD = $('#pgMenuDivTD');
    var pMN = $('#pgMenuDiv');

    var additionalOffset = ExpYes ? 3 : 0;

    var leftVal = (parseInt(pTD.offset().left) + parseInt(pTD.css('width'))) - (parseInt(pMN.css('width')) + additionalOffset);
    $('#pgMenuDiv').css('left', leftVal);
}
```

Comment: Three pixels is "far off to the right"? Also jQuery `css` method adds a default unit if needed. You could get an actual fix, if you just posted more code...

Comment: @Teemu - No, the 3px is an adjustment which covers the slight difference b/t the offset as calculated in IE (hence that ExpYes condition), vs where it really needs to be.  As for posting more code, if you look at the original question, it was edited 5 hours ago with a pastebin link.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't notice your link... Anyway, it seems there's different opinions in which browsers/modes the code is not working. Can you clear the issue? Also have you checked the actual code assigning the styles is having units? Quirks mode uses pixels by default, but in "HTML5" mode you must include the unit within a positioning rule... Also a narrowed-down example would be more suitable than a ton of code : (.